# Structure: Very Few Times

Tags: usage, inversion, quantifiers

I noticed on Google an inversion sentence structure of this form:

> [book source](http://books.google.com/books?id=G-cdxxEf0zcC&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=%22Very+few+times+will+%22&source=bl&ots=8Ga2ZdzDMg&sig=zQhDQB8Ih9seZ7z_4DXky9xnAXU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Sk6BU_yvKdGBoQSSBA&ved=0CCUQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22Very%20few%20times%20will%20%22&f=false)
> Very, ***very few times will*** the buyer's first offer be exactly at the seller's bottom price.

Could this be sloppy writing?  Would this:

> Very, ***very few times*** the buyer's first offer ***will*** be exactly at the seller's bottom price.

be better?

Answer (score 6):

When **negative phrases are fronted** (moved to the front of a clause), we typically apply subject-auxiliary inversion (the subject and auxiliary verb switch places).

In your example the negative phrase is "very, very few times", meaning "almost no".  The word *few* in this phrase is a special type of negative word, in technical terms called an **approximate negator** (because "few" is "close to zero").

Take a look at these example from *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL)*, page 95:

> *1a.*　He found **not one of them** useful.
>   *1b.*　**Not one of them** did he find useful.

The first example has the negative phrase *not one of them* in its basic position inside the clause.  In the second example, we've moved it to the front of the sentence.  Since it's negative, we apply subject-auxiliary inversion.  (And since we didn't have an auxiliary in 1a, we've added the dummy auxiliary *do* to make inversion possible.)

> *2a.*　**Somewhere** he mentions my book.
>   *2b.*　**Nowhere** does he mention my book.

In this pair of examples, we can see *somewhere* moved to the front without inversion.  This is fine, as *somewhere* is positive.  But *nowhere* is negative, so in 2b we've used inversion.

So no, you should not change the book's sentence.  It's just fine the way it is.

Comment: +1 It's not just negative phrases that are treated this way, though; see my answer.

Comment: Inversion is used for a lot of reasons besides this, of course!  And in many cases it's optional.  But I think the fronted negative is a specific trigger: "Nowhere he mentions my book!" is stranger than the inverted version.

Comment: It suddenly occurs to me that there may be a prosodic component here, too. The preferred stress pattern seems to be ++ 0 + 0, with tone falling from the ++ to the +; "rarely do we" see 3+-syllable words fronted this way. "Infrequently do we" just doesn't cut the mustard. ... and OP's example, "very very few times will the", is ++ 0 + 0 ++ 0 + 0.

Answer (score 3):

This construction emphasizes an adverbial or *BE* complement by moving it to the head of the sentence followed by Subject/Auxiliary inversion.

The construction is not so common as it once was*, but it is not yet rare or obsolete. My impression is that today it is almost exclusively a literary use, employed mostly with adverbials and adjectivals of frequency or quantity:

> Many were the days I spent on my grandfather's farm.
>   Often since then have I regretted my action.
>   Rarely do we see such strength coupled with such grace.

* See, for example, this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Never+have+I%2COften+have+I%2CMany+were+the%2CFew+were+the%2CRarely+have+I%2CHappy+is+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNever%20have%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COften%20have%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMany%20were%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFew%20were%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRarely%20have%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHappy%20is%20the%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Comment: Could it be that inversion is less common with positive phrases than negative phrases?

Comment: @meatie: yes, it is. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Very+often+will+he%2CVery+often+he+will%2CVery+rarely+will+he%2CVery+rarely+he+will&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVery%20often%20he%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CVery%20rarely%20will%20he%3B%2Cc0).