# 'Not until three years ago _________ to work outside.' [(a) he began (b) he begins (c) began he (d) did he begin ]

Tags: grammar, inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion

'Not until three years ago _________ to work outside.'

[(a) he began (b) he begins (c) began he (d) did he begin ]

Hi guys, I know the answer to this question is 'd', but I've had someone ask me the dreaded question: 'why?'

Can anyone help me to explain this? The student wants to know - why not answer 'a'?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Structure: Very Few Times](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24151/structure-very-few-times)

Answer (score 1):

It's a negative sentence so it requires do/did. Consider the following two sentences:

- He began to work outside.
- He *did not* begin to work outside.

Similarly,

- Three years ago, he began to work outside.
- Three years ago, he *did not* begin to work outside.
- Until three years ago, he *did not* begin to work outside.
- *Not* until three years ago, *did* he begin to work outside.

Comment: +1 Simple and to the point. But I would add that it requires did **and an inversion.**

Comment: Good point, thanks!